# Create a vector of occurrences the same size as an input string

Tags: python-2.7

I'm new to python and needed some help.

I have a string such a ACAACGG

I would now like to create 3 vectors where the elements are the counts of particular letter.

For example, for "A", this would produce (1123333)
For "C", this would produce (0111222)
etc.

I'm not sure how to put the results of the counting into an string or into a vector.
I believe this is similar to counting the occurrences of a character in a string, but I'm not sure how to have it run through the string and place the count value at each point.

For reference, I'm trying to implement the Burrows-Wheeler transform and use it for a string search.  But, I'm not sure how to create the occurrence vector for the characters.

```
def bwt(s):
  s = s + '$'
  return ''.join([x[-1] for x in
     sorted([s[i:] + s[:i] for i in range(len(s))])])
```

This gives me the transform and I'm trying to create the occurrence vector for it.  Ultimately, I want to use this to search for repeats in a DNA string.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what type you want the vectors to be in, but here's a function that returns a `list` of `int`s.

```py
 In [1]: def countervector(s, char):
   ....:     c = 0
   ....:     v = []
   ....:     for x in s:
   ....:         if x == char:
   ....:             c += 1
   ....:         v.append(c)
   ....:     return v
   ....: 

 In [2]: countervector('ACAACGG', 'A')
 Out[2]: [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]

 In [3]: countervector('ACAACGG', 'C')
 Out[3]: [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

Also, here's a much shorter way to do it, but it will probably be inefficient on long strings:

```py
def countervector(s, char):
    return [s[:i+1].count(char) for i, _ in enumerate(s)]
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I was able to go over this an get it in the fashion I wanted.  I'm not very familiar with the .append commands and that is what I was looking for.  Also, the assignment of an empty object helped.  I'll post my script when finished.

Comment: Have a look at what you can do with lists [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

Answer (score 0):

As promised here is the finished script I wrote.  For reference, I'm trying to use the Burrows-Wheeler transform to do repeat matching in strings of DNA.  Basically the idea is to take a strand of DNA of some length M and find all repeat within that string.  So, as an example, if I had strange acaacg and searched for all duplicated substrings of size 2, I would get a count of 1 and the starting locations of 0,3.  You could then type in string[0:2] and string[3:5] to verify that they do actually match and their result is "ac".

If anyone is interested in learning about the Burrows-Wheeler, a Wikipedia search on it produces very helpful results.  Here's is another source from Stanford that also explains it well.  http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs262/notes/lecture5.pdf

Now, there are a few issues that I did not address in this.  First, I'm using n^2 space to create the BW transform.  Also, I'm creating a suffix array, sorting it, and then replacing it with numbers so creating that may take up a bit of space.  However, at the end I'm only really storing the occ matrix, the end column, and the word itself.

Despite the RAM problems for strings larger that 4^7 (got this to work with a string size of 40,000 but no larger...), I would call this a success seeing as before Monday, the only thing I new how to do in python was to have it print my name and hello world.

```
#  generate random string of DNA
def get_string(length):
    string=""
    for i in range(length):
        string += random.choice("ATGC")
    return string

#  Make the BW transform from the generated string  
def make_bwt(word):
    word = word + '$'
    return ''.join([x[-1] for x in
        sorted([word[i:] + word[:i] for i in range(len(word))])])
#  Make the occurrence matrix from the transform        
def make_occ(bwt):
    letters=set(bwt)
    occ={}
    for letter in letters:
        c=0
        occ[letter]=[]
        for i in range(len(bwt)):
            if bwt[i]==letter:
            c+=1
            occ[letter].append(c)
    return occ

#  Get the initial starting locations for the Pos(x) values 
def get_starts(word):
    list={}
    word=word+"$"
    for letter in set(word):
        list[letter]=len([i for i in word if i < letter])
    return list

#  Single range finder for the BWT.  This produces a first and last position for one read.  
def get_range(read,occ,pos):
    read=read[::-1]
    firstletter=read[0]
    newread=read[1:len(read)]
    readL=len(read)
    F0=pos[firstletter]
    L0=pos[firstletter]+occ[firstletter][-1]-1

    F1=F0
    L1=L0
    for letter in newread:
        F1=pos[letter]+occ[letter][F1-1]
        L1=pos[letter]+occ[letter][L1] -1
    return F1,L1

#  Iterate the single read finder over the entire string to search for duplicates   
def get_range_large(readlength,occ,pos,bwt):
    output=[]
    for i in range(0,len(bwt)-readlength):
        output.append(get_range(word[i:(i+readlength)],occ,pos))
    return output

#  Create suffix array to use later 
def get_suf_array(word):
    suffix_names=[word[i:] for i in range(len(word))]   
    suffix_position=range(0,len(word))                  
    output=zip(suffix_names,suffix_position)
    output.sort()
    output2=[]
    for i in range(len(output)):                        
        output2.append(output[i][1])
    return output2

#  Remove single hits that were a result of using the substrings to scan the large string   
def keep_dupes(bwtrange):
    mylist=[]
    for i in range(0,len(bwtrange)):
        if bwtrange[i][1]!=bwtrange[i][0]:
            mylist.append(tuple(bwtrange[i]))
    newset=set(mylist)
    newlist=list(newset)
    newlist.sort()
    return newlist

#  Count the duplicate entries
def count_dupes(hits):
    c=0
    for i in range(0,len(hits)):
        sum=hits[i][1]-hits[i][0]
        if sum > 0:
            c=c+sum
        else:
            c
    return c

#  Get the coordinates from BWT and use the suffix array to map them back to their original indices 
def get_coord(hits):
    mylist=[]
    for element in hits:
        mylist.append(sa[element[0]-1:element[1]])
    return mylist

#  Use the coordinates to get the actual strings that are duplicated
def get_dupstrings(coord,readlength):
    output=[]
    for element in coord:
        temp=[]
        for i in range(0,len(element)):         
            string=word[element[i]:(element[i]+readlength)]
            temp.append(string)
        output.append(temp) 
    return output

#  Merge the strings and the coordinates together for one big list. 
def together(dupstrings,coord):
    output=[]
    for i in range(0,len(coord)):
        merge=dupstrings[i]+coord[i]
        output.append(merge)
    return output

Now run the commands as follows
import random  #  This is needed to generate a random string
readlength=12 #  pick read length
word=get_string(4**7) # make random word
bwt=make_bwt(word) # make bwt transform from word
occ=make_occ(bwt)  #  make occurrence matrix  
pos=get_starts(word)  #  gets start positions of sorted first row       
bwtrange=get_range_large(readlength,occ,pos,bwt) #  Runs the get_range function over all substrings in a string.    
sa=get_suf_array(word)  #  This function builds a suffix array and numbers it.  
hits=keep_dupes(bwtrange)   #  Pulls out the number of entries in the bwt results that have more than one hit.
dupes=count_dupes(hits) #  counts hits
coord=get_coord(hits)  #  This part attempts to pull out the coordinates of the hits.  
dupstrings=get_dupstrings(coord,readlength)  #  pulls out all the duplicated strings
strings_coord=together(dupstrings,coord)    #  puts coordinates and strings in one file for ease of viewing.
print dupes
print strings_coord
```